Html not loaded even after window.addEventListener('load', do_something) is invoked
I'm working on a browser extension that scrapes data from a webpage. I've added a method to scrape data, which is invoked via a load listener:
window.addEventListener('load', scrapeSomething)
However, when I refresh the page and put a breakpoint in the Chrome Developer Tools, I notice that the HTML is still not fully loaded when the method is invoked. For instance, the HTML content at the time of invocation is just:
<div id="hiddenFrame"></div>
To mitigate this issue temporarily, the previous code had a 5-second delay before running the scraping logic:
let callDebouncer = () => {
setTimeout(() => {
//scraping part
},5000);  };
window.addEventListener('load', callDebouncer);

I want to avoid using a fixed delay and instead rely on a listener to ensure the page is fully loaded before scraping. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

dynamic sites require expertise to borrow from

window.load fires when everything is loaded into window. Most likely there's no other content to load on the page you're navigating to.

So why does a 5 second delay allow the site to be "borrowed" from if there's no other content @Teemu

@Teemu, I don't think that is the case as after I move past the break point other html loads after 2 to 5 seconds

@JaromandaX I guess there is, a script in the head section, maybe using a timeout to create more content, or even a meta tag re-directing the page,

"to ensure the page is fully loaded" - there's no way to know this.  If the page uses javascript to build html, it could do it at any time.  If the page uses ajax to build the html, it could load some, then load some more.  eg a "chat" app would never be "fully loaded".   If it's for a specific page, you would need to reverse-engineer what that page is doing.

Also to add , I have never faced this issue when I go to the page in a traditional way  (go through login screen and then go to sections) , I only face this when the scraping happened and I refresh the page then the scraping happens before the elements in the xpaths are loaded

@TharunReddy: Scraping a web page is an exercise in reverse-engineering.  If that page is dynamically loading information or dynamically modifying its content after the page has loaded then you'd need to find out where/how that's happening to account for it.  Maybe the page is making AJAX calls that you can monitor?  Maybe something else?  They could be doing anything really.  Perhaps instead of an artificial delay you can introduce an interval that keeps checking for a specific element to exist and then proceeds with the logic when it does?

I think the waiting for an element to exist is valid , However Currently the scraping is one by an extension which gets the paths to scrape via an API call depending on the website, So might have to add a whole new functionality to implement waiting logic for a specific element

What site are you trying to scrape? are you sure an extension is the right tool for this? is this extension for personal use or going to be published?
